# TypeError: 'MultiLineString' object is not iterable

Tags: python, plot, geopandas

I was following a genetic algorithm for bus route optimization in github https://github.com/Schmidtbit/Bus-Route-Optimization. I fixed most of the errors I encountered except this one TypeError: 'MultiLineString' object is not iterable when plotting the route network.

```
def plot(self):
    '''
    OUTPUT: plot of routes
    '''

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,12))
    for n in range(self.N):
        # Make LineString Objects
        route_a_line = self.route_line(self.route_list[n][1])
        route_b_line = self.route_line(self.route_list[n][2])

        # Make Geo DataFrames
        route_a_geo = self.transform_to_GeoDataFrame(route_a_line)
        route_b_geo = self.transform_to_GeoDataFrame(route_b_line)

        ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,n+1)
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
        
        print(self.roads.geometry)
        
        self.roads.plot(ax=ax,color='black', linewidth=.5 )
        self.region.plot(ax=ax, color='orange', alpha=.2)
        self.bus_stops_geo.plot(ax=ax, color='red',markersize=8)

        route_a_geo.plot(ax=ax, color='green', linewidth=1)
        route_b_geo.plot(ax=ax, color='blue', linewidth=1)

        ax.set_title('East Side Route Map {}\nFitness = {}'.format(n+1,self.route_list[n][0]))
        ax.set_ylim((self.miny, self.maxy))
        ax.set_xlim((self.minx, self.maxx))
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])

    plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=.1, hspace=.1)
    plt.show()
```

Output

```
40       LINESTRING (-97.68178 30.28154, -97.68239 30.2...103      LINESTRING (-97.68271 30.28083, -97.68212 30.2...145      LINESTRING (-97.69771 30.25189, -97.69632 30.2...146      LINESTRING (-97.72316 30.28912, -97.72312 30.2...157      LINESTRING (-97.73329 30.27056, -97.73312 30.2......19248    LINESTRING (-97.71925 30.27073, -97.71828 30.2...19374    LINESTRING (-97.73050 30.27595, -97.73046 30.2...19393    LINESTRING (-97.73050 30.27595, -97.73046 30.2...19416    LINESTRING (-97.71351 30.25043, -97.71343 30.2...19553    LINESTRING (-97.73230 30.24584, -97.73143 30.2...Name: geometry, Length: 662, dtype: geometry

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)Cell In[16], line 1----> 1 model.plot()

File ~\Downloads\Bus-Route-Optimization-master\RouteFinder1.0\RouteFinder.py:296, in RouteFinder.plot(self)288 print(self.roads.geometry)290 #if (self.roads.geometry.type == 'MultiLineString').any():291 #    for line in self.roads.geometry:292 #        ax.plot(*line.xy, color='black', linewidth=.5)293 #else:294 #    ax.plot(*self.roads.geometry.xy, color='black', linewidth=.5)--> 296 self.roads.plot(ax=ax,color='black', linewidth=.5 )297 self.region.plot(ax=ax, color='orange', alpha=.2)298 self.bus_stops_geo.plot(ax=ax, color='red',markersize=8)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py:606, in GeoDataFrame.plot(self, *args, **kwargs)596 def plot(self, *args, **kwargs):597     """Generate a plot of the geometries in the GeoDataFrame.598599     If the column parameter is given, colors plot according to values(...)604     from there.605     """--> 606     return plot_dataframe(self, *args, **kwargs)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\plotting.py:495, in plot_dataframe(df, column, cmap, color, ax, cax, categorical, legend, scheme, k, vmin, vmax, markersize, figsize, legend_kwds, classification_kwds, **style_kwds)492     markersize = df[markersize].values494 if column is None:--> 495     return plot_series(496         df.geometry,497         cmap=cmap,498         color=color,499         ax=ax,500         figsize=figsize,501         markersize=markersize,502         **style_kwds503     )505 # To accept pd.Series and np.arrays as column506 if isinstance(column, (np.ndarray, pd.Series)):

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\plotting.py:348, in plot_series(s, cmap, color, ax, figsize, **style_kwds)346 if not lines.empty:347     values_ = values[line_idx] if cmap else None--> 348     plot_linestring_collection(349         ax, lines, values_, color=color, cmap=cmap, **style_kwds350     )352 # plot all Points in the same collection353 points = s.geometry[point_idx]

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\plotting.py:156, in plot_linestring_collection(ax, geoms, values, color, cmap, vmin, vmax, **kwargs)129 """130 Plots a collection of LineString and MultiLineString geometries to ax131(...)152153 """154 from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection--> 156 geoms, multiindex = _flatten_multi_geoms(geoms, range(len(geoms)))157 if values is not None:158     values = np.take(values, multiindex)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\plotting.py:38, in _flatten_multi_geoms(geoms, colors)36 for geom, color in zip(geoms, colors):37     if geom.type.startswith("Multi"):---> 38         for poly in geom:39             components.append(poly)40             # repeat same color for all components

TypeError: 'MultiLineString' object is not iterable
```

I keep getting TypeError: 'MultiLineString' object is not iterable which is tied to self.roads.plot(ax=ax,color='black', linewidth=.5 ) but isn't roads a linestring obj and not multilinestring as printed in the output?

I am using geopandas=0.6.0
threadpoolctl=3.2.0

- I have tried googling the error TypeError: 'MultiLineString' object is not iterable but the only solution I found was not related to plotting.
- I also tried asking ChatGPT about the error but it kept giving me code to check if the object was multistring and plotting it in xy which gave me a bad plot of the road network and a NotImplementedError: error.

Comment: GeoPandas 0.6.0 is from 2019. Updating to 0.13 or anything close to that will likely resolve all your issues.